# Change the title for the default top level window

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

In my script, I didn't explicitly define a top level window. Now I want to change the title for the window (by default the title is the script name) by the following code:

```
ttk::notebook .nb_whole
wm title .nb_whole "ok"
```

but the error message said the `.nb_whole` is not the top window. How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top level window of your application is named `.`. `wm title . ok` should work.

Documentation: [wm](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm)